# Determine whether Siemens S7 400 PLC has Memory card from Project

Tags: plc

Does anyone know if I can determine whether a Memory card is installed in a Siemens PLC from the Step 7 Project?

Thanks,

GLMT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the project you can see the Memory Requirements for each block by right clicking and selecting Object Properties.  You should be able to modify the view settings to show this property for all blocks.  You can get a rough value of memory of your blocks from this.  You can compare this to the internal memory of the PLC you are using.  Beware this figure doesn't take into account system data blocks.  Generally any S7300/S7400 PLC projects I worked on habe used memory cards..

Comment: Thanks AM. Speaking to some other colleagues as well this seems to be the consensus. It would be nice if the card could be added as a configuration parameter!